# Good game for parents to play with 4 year old son?

Tags: recommendations

What would the best board game be for mother and father to play with their 4 year old so?

I was recommended Exploding Kittens or King Of Tokyo, but Amazon says that they are for ages 8+.

Comment: StackExhange sites such as this one are not well suited to provide recommendations.

Comment: @ikegami Well, the existence of a recommendations tag with ~75 questions does make that confusing.

Comment: Hey, That's My Fish! or Loopin Chewie would be my suggestions

Comment: @Mattmatt yet clicking the tag shows it is "generally off-topic" and the tag is "primarily for historical reasons". Going to learn note explains in depth that these questions *are off-topic* and that they are not accepted.

Comment: @Matt, 1) I added that tag to the question, so the OP wasn't confused by that. 2) Every single question with that tag is closed. 3) The description for [tag:recommendations] is "*Generally off-topic. Suggestions for games that meet specific requirements. (tag exists primarily for historical reasons)*"

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I am aware of all of those things (except that the op didnt add the tag). It doesnt change the fact that people dont read tag descriptions for tags that seem self explanatory and people certainly dont look up historic use of the tag to notice the questions are all closed.

Comment: @Matt, So maybe someone should tell people who get it wrong... Oh wait, that's what I did!

Comment: Reasons for having the tag aside, these sites exist to help people, so my own grievances with the decisions by the powers-that-be aside.... my 2c is that it depends. I've got lots of cousins and they have varied wildly in game-playing ability, and it all comes down to the 4yo in question. My advice is just to try one and see, and if they can't grasp it yet, you can just play it in a few years. Exploding kittens may not be the best as there's lots of text, and the vindictive/random nature of play can be frustrating for adults, let alone toddlers. Haven't played King of Tokyo to comment

Comment: HABA Dancing Eggs Game which I once played in a pub, with alcohol handicapped adults. It's a hilarious physical game, I know a 2 yo who would love seeing their parents play it and acting silly, the game says 5+ so your little one could probably join in. You'd probably be quite verbally encouraging in this game, it's quite active so it wouldn't be suitable before bedtime! Or for a quieter one, funnily enough same company HABA Rhino Hero (5+), it's a dexterity game where you stack cards up. I'd imagine this would be more of a "be quiet, be still, we don't want to push it over" game